# android 10 error type=1400 audit(0.0:77): avc: granted { execute } for name="busybox" dev="vdc" ino=36845 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:

Tags: android, android-studio, android-10.0

i get this error on android studio when i set targetSdkVersion 29 or 30 anybody has any idea what is wrong? on targetSdkVersion 28 is work ok on any android version

type=1400 audit(0.0:77): avc: granted { execute } for name="busybox" dev="vdc" ino=36845 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c137,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c137,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com

I guess it has something to do with this:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10
Removed execute permission for app home directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64792194/1924192) an answer about this new limitation introduced in Android 10, which restricts where executable files can still have execute permission when using targetSdkVersion 29 or above.

Cheers, Jérôme

Answer (score 0):

If your target is lower than the version on the phone, you are running in compatibility mode, therefore some restrictions don't apply.

This is done so new OS versions don't break existing apps made for earlier OS versions.
Don't count on this working for a long time, in the next OS versions that restriction might apply even for apps targeting lower SDK

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Platform.isAndroid`
I am using flutter, this code is in Dart language, I used it in this function and it solved the error

```
import 'dart:io';

 Future<Directory> getDirectory() async {
    Directory directory;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      var androidDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      directory = Directory('${androidDir!.path}/Your_folder_name');
      return directory;

    } else {
      directory = Directory('/sdcard/Your_folder_name');
      return directory;
    }
  }
```